# wine DirectX diagnostics (dxdiag) on completely fresh WINE prefix is not showing any window - is it expected?

Tags: wine

When I create completely new wine prefix:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/fresh" wine wineboot
```

and try to run `dxiag` on it:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/fresh" wine dxdiag
```

I see only an error in the console:

> 0009:err:winediag:MIDIMAP_drvOpen No software synthesizer midi port
>   found, Midi sound output probably won't work.

but no window appears.

Problem (? or is it expected?) exists on both 32 and 64 wine prefixes.
I use wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1).

Comment: For me it additionally prints `0009:fixme:dxdiag:wWinMain Information dialog is not implemented` *(wine 3.13 here)*, which probably means it's not implemented. And a cursory search brings me the same thought. So, yeah, most probably it's expected. I kind of see the justification — the efforts for a graphical information dialog could probably be better spent improving Wine infrastructure and fixing bugs.

Comment: I don't see mentioned information (do I need to run wine in some kind of debug mode?). Is there any possibility to test wine prefix for DirectX? Or more generally - test wine prefix other than installation of particular application?

Comment: I'd guess this print was added later than 3.0 *(which is very old btw)*. Try simply installing a more recent Wine version, e.g. from a PPA. Your second-third question I didn't really understand… perhaps are you asking for `WINEPREFIX` variable? It an environment variable that allows you to override the wine prefix. E.g. by default you have `~/.wine`, you can move it to `~/.wineBCKP`, and run apps from there as `WINEPREFIX=~/.wineBCKP wine myapp.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get dxdiag working.. But to get that working you need to & download install [directx_apr2006_redist.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20100920035904/https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/9/7/3972f80c-5711-4e14-9483-959d48a2d03b/directx_apr2006_redist.exe) under your Wine bottle.

Or use [winetricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks).., like so: `winetricks dxdiag`

The default shipped dxdiag is broken.

**Hint:** You can change your bottle by setting WINEPREFIX=/path/to/your/bottle before executing the `winetricks` or `wine` command.